# MySql filter by multiple entries from same table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`entries`
**id | name | entry**

`filters` **id | eid | name | value**

In first table there are all posts stored and in the second one there is settings for each post. For example:

`entries` contains **1 | First post | Lorem Ipsum**

`filters` contains

**1 | 1 | date_posted | 2013-06-19**

**2 | 1 | author | admin**

**3 | 1 | view_count | 578**

I need to filter all posts where author is admin and view count is bigger than 300, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT e.id,
       e.name,
       e.entry
FROM   entries e
       LEFT JOIN filters a
              ON a.eid = e.id
                 AND a.name = 'author'
       LEFT JOIN filters v
              ON v.eid = e.id
                 AND v.name = 'view_count'
WHERE  a.value = 'admin'
       AND v.value > 300
```

Comment: and I have one more question - if filters table will contain about 50k entries and I will need to filter entries by ~10-20 values would it be very slow?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "very slow". With indexes, it should be OK.